# how to hide icons (in statusbar and navigationbar) like google photos app

Tags: android-actionbar, navigationbar, android-icons

The Google photos app can hide the icons in the navigation bar, status bar and action bar. 
I would like to know how to do this.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your activity

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```